# How to add class cookie by javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

i don't want to change class after page loaded. How to add class cookie in my project.

**HTML**
    Red
    Green

```
<div class="red">Testing Text1</div>
<div class="red">Testing Text2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.green {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}`
```

**Javascript**

```
  function changeClass(value) {
     var color1 = 'red';
     var color2 = 'green';
     if (value == 2) {
         color1 = 'green';
         color2 = 'red';
     };

     var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(color1);
     var i = elems.length;
     while (i--) {
         var item = elems[i];
         if (hasClass(item, color1)) {
             removeClass(item, color1);
             addClass(item, color2);
         }
     };
     return false;
 };

 function hasClass(ele, cls) {
     return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
 }

 function addClass(ele, cls) {
     if (!hasClass(ele, cls)) ele.className += " " + cls;
 }

 function removeClass(ele, cls) {
     if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
         var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
         ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, ' ');
     }
 }
```

Comment: where do u need to add class ?

Comment: Sry.i want to add cookie. not class.

Answer (score 0):

For adding Cookies in JS

```
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
  {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
  }
```

For getting Cookies in jS

```
function getCookie(cname) 
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
 }
  return "";
}
```

Now,you can use this Funcations any where in your code and Call it.

Comment: where add cookies to my project.

Comment: I mean all class name in the whole element is "green" when click "green" and then not change class name after page lode.